# Trying to create a weighted directed cycle graph

Tags: netlogo

I have a complete weighted directed graph. My goal is to allow each turtle to only have one in-link and one out-link (which will result in a directed cycle graph) whilst making sure the sum total of the weights are maximum.
To do this, I have listed the maximum in-link (or out-link) of every turtle (without consideration of the above rules) and now I'm trying to delete all out-links of end1 of the maximum link and all in-links of end2 of the link. When deleted the initial list of maximum links has to be updated. This process continues until there are no more links to choose from.
This is the code I have so far:

```
    foreach sort-on [(- label)] link-set [max-one-of my-in-links [label]] of turtles
   [
    ask the-links [ask end1 [ask my-out-links with [not member? myself x] [die]]]
    ask the-links [ask end2 [ask my-in-links with [not member? myself x] [die]]]
   ]
```

I think until I don't update the maximum links the code cannot run properly because it keeps saying "the link has died". However, even if i manage to update the maximum links I'm not sure the "myself x" part is correct.
what can I do solve this problem?